# Can Django manage.py custom commands return a value? How, or why not?

Tags: python, django, django-commands

Following the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

I created my own custom command (called something else but example shown below):

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from polls.models import Poll

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<poll_id poll_id ...>'
    help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for poll_id in args:
            try:
                poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=int(poll_id))
            except Poll.DoesNotExist:
                raise CommandError('Poll "%s" does not exist' % poll_id)

            poll.opened = False
            poll.save()

            self.stdout.write('Successfully closed poll "%s"' % poll_id)

        return "Yay"
```

The question is how come returning a string like "Yay" does not work?
Am I doing it wrong or is it not possible?

When I call the custom command from my view, I do something like:

```
     value = call_command('call_custom_command', parameter)
     print value
```

but the value is shown to be None.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to get the output of `call_command()`, you need to capture stdout. Here's how you can do it:

```
out = StringIO()
call_command('call_custom_command', stdout=out)

value = out.getvalue()
print value
```

This technique is actually used in [django tests](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/user_commands/tests.py) for testing management commands.

Demo:

```
>>> from django.core.management import call_command
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> call_command('validate', stdout=out)
>>> out.getvalue()
'0 errors found\n'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it totally worked. the stdout will get both your self.stdout.write('values') and your return value; So, I parsed the entire out.getvalue() and everything works. Thanks!

Comment: # for python3 use ->> 
from io import StringIO

Comment: This works if you `return` something from the management command. If you just print, it won't work