# Django management - execute command with continuous output

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a script that I'm building an interface for so people can execute after uploading a CSV file. I'm able to execute everything and have the script run properly, but how do I display a continuous output? What changes should I make to my code?

Below are my files:

scripts.html - Scripts are executed from here and executed on the server via an AJAX call. Output is placed into div#output once the script is done executing.

```
<div class="table_container">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">{% csrf_token %}
        <h4>Rebilling</h4>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <img class="loading-gif" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/loading-clear.gif" alt="" />
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 180px;"><label>Upload the CSV</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="script_type" value="renew_subscriptions">
                    <input type="file" name="csv_file" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 180px;"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="Execute" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form> 
</div>

<h2>Script Output</h2>
<div id="output">
    {% autoescape off %}

    {% endautoescape %}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Variable to store your files
    var files;

    // Add events
    $('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

    // Grab the files and set them to our variable
    function prepareUpload(event)
    {
      files = event.target.files;
    }

    $('form').on('submit', submitForm);

    // Catch the form submit and upload the files
    function submitForm(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
        event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening
        $("#output").html("");

        var form = $(this);
        form.find(".loading-gif").css("display", "block");
        form.find("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', true);

        // Create a formdata object and add the files
        var data = new FormData(form.get(0));

        $.ajax({
            url: '/crm/scripts',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                // console.dir(data);
                $("#output").html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                form.find(".loading-gif").css("display", "none");
                form.find("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });


        return false;
    }
</script>
```

views.py - The AJAX is sent here and the command is executed through Django Management

```
def all_scripts(request):    # Accounts page
    # c = {}
    script_type = None
    csv_file = None
    out = StringIO()

    if request.is_ajax and request.method == 'POST':
        csv_file = request.FILES.get('csv_file')

        if csv_file:
            # print "over here"
            ### write the csv_file to a temp file
            tup = tempfile.mkstemp() # make a tmp file
            f = os.fdopen(tup[0], 'w') # open the tmp file for writing
            f.write(csv_file.read()) # write the tmp file
            f.close()

            ### return the path of the file
            filepath = tup[1] # get the filepath
            # print filepath

            if 'script_type' in request.POST:
                script_type = request.POST['script_type']
                if script_type == "change_credit":
                    credit_amount = None

                    if 'credit_amount' in request.POST:
                        credit_amount = request.POST['credit_amount']

                    if 'function' in request.POST:
                        function = request.POST['function']

                        if function == "remove":
                            management.call_command(script_type, filepath, credit_amount, remove=[True], stdout=out)
                        else:
                            management.call_command(script_type, filepath, credit_amount, stdout=out)

                elif script_type == "renew_subscriptions":
                    management.call_command(script_type, filepath, verbosity=1, interactive=False, stdout=out)

                print out.getvalue()
                return HttpResponse(out.getvalue())

    return render_to_response('crm/scripts.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Just need the output to display continuously line by line. Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers,
Zee

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What is wrong with the code you showed us? Does it not work? Does it produce unexpected behavior?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the post to include a question. My question is essentially, what do I change so I can have a continuous output to display?

Comment: @Cyber does that clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> “The web request is a scary place, you want to get in and out as quick
>   as you can” - Rick Branson

What you have done here is created an architectural issue. Basically you are creating additional disk IO when writing your CSV file. **You are doing this in the web request.** 'Not a good idea'.

However its also the crux of the issue you are describing.

**Quick n dirty:** 
you could get a return value from a django management command [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571528/1184492). Pass that back to the success method of jquery's ajax call as your data.

However: **please don't to that!**

You need an **async task system to hand off** the write of that csv file. Additionally you want to write the data somewhere ( dbms / nosql ) that your webpage can listen for via ( [polling, streaming or websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12855533/1184492) ) This is not a trivial undertaking but the end result is well worth the effort. Here are some [proven django-stack choices](http://www.jeffield.net/2013/11/the-web-request-is-a-scary-place/) to solve this type of issue.

**Building a Asynchronous Tasking/Queuing System**

- [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)
- [Rabbit](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) the broker used by celery
- [memcached](http://memcached.org/) / [mongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) /  [reddis](http://redis.io/)

**Polling for that data**

- what are [longpolling and websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12855533/1184492)
- [websockets vs long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10029326/1184492)

**This pycon talk covers these technologies**.

- [Messaging at Scale at Instagram](http://pyvideo.org/video/1671/messaging-at-scale-at-instagram)